# renaming ID's entity in Core Data more than once? (for third version)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, versioning

how can i change the name of my model's entity more than once : let's say from version 1 to 2, my entity changes from "Entity" to "MyEntity", and then from 2 to 3, it changes from "MyEntity" to "MyLastEntity" ?

In order to change the name from version 1 to 2, i put in both versions the same name in "renaming ID" (in "Versioning"), but how should i make the change from version 2 to 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it exactly the same way by adding a third model version so that you remain backwards compatible for both versions.

Comment: ok if i have a new (third) version, i put a new name in "Renaming ID", and like version 1 to 2, should i also change the name of this "Renaming ID" in previous versions (in the 3 of them)?

Comment: No,  it does the ingestion from 1 to 2 and **then** from 2 to 3 so don't touch number 1.  Just pretend that 1 isn't there and migrate from 2 to 3 the same as before.

Comment: Apparently we should put the name from the first version (« Entity ») into the third one (« MyLastEntity ») right? If I put the second name (« MyEntity ») in the third, my data are not migrated and are removed. Seems strange because Core Data should be aware of the progressive update no?